# Javascript ContextMenu on a TD

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

If I attach a context menu to a td, it fires okay for text in the TD, but if I add a div to the TD, the context menu will not fire when right clicking on the div.  How can I make the context menu fire when anything, data or divs, are right clicked in the td?

Edit: The event was popping, but due to an error in my code, I never saw the event popping.  Sorry for not posting code earlier, I didn't check back until someone "answered" the question and I received an email.  Thanks for all the effort to answer the question.  The "right" answer is that the question was flawed.

Comment: can you post some code? Pretty hard to answer without it...

Comment: I agree, we need some code because the events should work thier way down. Here is a simple example <table> <tr> <td onclick="alert('td')"><div onclick="alert('div')">Hello</div></td> </tr> </table> The term for this is called event bubbling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to a bug in my code, the question was invalid

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set div's width and hight to 100%

s